# how to change the color of command with oh_my_zsh's theme?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

My problem is:

I can not see the command clearly.

I want to change its color to improve contrast.
I can not distinguish it easily now

### [image]

`Environment:`

`terminal-emulator: xfce4-terminal`

`system:ubuntu20.04`

`zsh-version:5.8-3ubuntu1(focal)`

~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/bullet-train.zsh-theme is:

[bullet-train.zsh-theme](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BpYPJtW2wg/)

---

Did I check the settings in `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/bullet-train.zsh-theme`?

Yes,I searched the keyword `blue` in above theme file.

but no setting is relevant to command.

---

Did I check the settings of xfce4-terminal?

Yes!
But no settings work.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

The `zle_highlight` array allows you to format the command buffer. For example, to make the text in the buffer bold, add to your `.zshrc` (or your theme)

```
zle_highlight=(bold)
```

Consult the `zshzle` man page for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.but it did not work after I set zle_highlight=(white) in ~/.zshrc